# Storing user permissions in a table

Tags: c#, sql

I was wondering if anyone have a good tip regarding storing userpermissions in a table.

To have a structure like this:

```
int ID
int UserID
bit Permission1
bit Permission2
bit Permission3
...
bit Permission50
```

Seems a bit clunky. Is there any smart way to store these? Anyone have a good tip on a solution that doesn't require adding new columns when new permissions are added?

Any method is extra good handled in C#, when working with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have one permission-column and store the name/id of the permission:

```
ID       userID     permissionID
------   -------    -------------
1        4711       15
2        4711       23
3        4743       15
4        4711       36
```

and so on...

Then instead of checking some bitmask just select wether an entry with the required permission exists.

Comment: Thank you, of course!. I must really be tired today! :P Accepted